# Creating variables from piped commands that contain single quotes

Tags: bash, docker, scripting

I'm trying to chain various commands to automate a common docker process. This isn't a docker thing, it's more of a trying-to-automate-it-in-bash thing.

I can run:

```
docker ps | grep manager | cut -f -d ' '
```

which lists the current docker containers, singles out one that contains the word 'manager' and then grabs the first field which is the container id eg 3a5455f3ac72

I can then run:

```
docker inspect -f'{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}} 3a5455f3ac72
```

which gets the IP address of the docker container eg 172.18.0.4

What I would like to achieve is a variable called container_id and a variable called container_IP that I can use in bash scripts. I have tried:

```
container_id="docker ps | grep manager | cut -f 1 -d ' '"
container_ip='docker inspect -f'{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $container_id'
```

But when I try to create the container_id variable, I get:

```
invalid argument "1" for "-f, --filter" flag: bad format of filter (expected name=value)
See 'docker ps --help'.
```

I think I have an error in how I'm using single/double quotes, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You might to use process substitutions, for ex. `container_id="$(docker ps  | ...)"`, instead of literal strings for setting your variables

Comment: Storing commands in variables doesn't work very well; fundamentally, variables are for storing data, not executable code. To store code, you generally want a function instead. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: For one, the `docker inspect` IP address is all but useless; it's only accessible at all on one specific host OS setup, and then only from the same host.  Do you want to use a published port instead, which will be more portable and may not require any `docker` commands at all?

Comment: @Fravadona That's a command substitution. A process substitution uses `<(...)` as the delimiters, and acts as the name of a file whose contents come from the enclosed command's standard output.

Comment: Why does `$container_id'` ends in a single quote? Are there other lines?

Comment: Instead of using `docker ps` to grab `container_id` why not give it some known name using `-name` option while running your container and later use that name in `inspect` command

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - that simplified things a lot and it works. Though I will look to refactor it based on what Gordon said - code goes in functions, data goes in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could look like the following:

```
container_id() {
   docker ps -f 'name=manager' --format '{{.ID}}'
}
container_ip() {
   local id
   id=$(container_id)
   docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' "$id"
}

container_ip
```

> an error in how I'm using single/double quotes

Quotes do not matter here. Do not store commands as strings. Use functions to store commands. Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck. Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

> Creating variables from piped commands that contain single quotes

To create variables, execute the commands with command substitution. Instead of functions, you can just execute the commands:

```
container_id=$(docker ps | grep manager | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
container_ip=$(docker inspect -f'{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' "$container_id")
echo "$container_ip"
```

Comment: The first command pipeline should probably be refactored to a single `docker ps -q --filter '...'` command; this should improve both performance and precision.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, which worked for my use case. I followed this up with `sed -i 's/MANAGER_IP/'"$container_ip"'/g' file.txt` to replace a generic placeholder in file.txt for the container id with the actual ip.